# Can we use sample code given by microsoft which it has mentioned to be associated with a white paper

Tags: .net

`DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll` is a library provided by microsoft. We can dowload this from [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23459).

**The overview given by microsoft is** 
Windows Forms sample code for adding drop-down filter lists to the DataGridView control similar to the AutoFilter feature of Excel. **This sample code is associated with a white paper on this topic**

My question is, Can i directly use it in my application without bothering about the licence issues? I'm working in a business firm. I need this for my business application.

Comment: Each code file has some legal text in the header which absolves MS from any responsibility of using it, but unfortunately it doesn't cover usage or copyright, so it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Any code provided on MSDN subject to the [MSDN Terms of Use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc300389.aspx). Using this code means you agree to it. I suppose that all sample code from the Microsoft website is under that license.

Comment: To quote "*Your use of Software is governed by the terms of the license agreement, if any, that accompanies or is included with the Software.*" I couldn't see one that grants usage clearly. Maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: The Terms of Use doesn't exactly say that you can't use their code samples for commercial purposes, does it? So that technically means that you can use the code in your own projects. Such a quality is similar to the open source MIT License, except that Microsoft uses their lawyers to sprinkle tons of _legalese_ on their license.

Comment: @desbet I'm not trying to be cute. Have you read the license that is included with each source code file? It's nothing like the MIT license, it does not grant any permissions.

Comment: I searched the Terms of Use for the word commercial, found 2 matches, read the clauses, then formed my judgement on it.

Comment: @desbet But each source code file has it's own disclaimer, see "*that accompanies or is included with the Software*".

Comment: If it has its own disclaimer, you should refer to that for the software license. If you find that it has no license, you are legally allowed to use the code in your own work, if it was part of a code snippet designed to help people. In the same way work I post on the internet automatically gains copyright without me disclosing it, code snippets that don't have a software license, that you get in white papers, you're freely allowed to do what you want with.

Comment: @desbet It *does* have it's own disclaimer, that's the point I'm trying to make, never mind...